# MVC view returning 404 error even with a controller

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, model-view-controller, http-status-code-404

Every time I try to add a new view to my project, with the appropriate controller, the view will always display a 404 error. I've tried deleting and recreating the view and controller, creating views with different names and functions all with controllers, hard coding the file path, nothing. All the other views in the program work fine just now adding any view with any name won't work even with the proper controller.

```
    public ActionResult CreateAccount()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

The location and name of the view:
[Location and name of the view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UeHT.png)

the only code in the view is:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

and the link to the page is

@Html.ActionLink("Create Account", "CreateAccount", "Home")

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Eddit: Full Home Controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using --Program--.Models;
using --Program--.DataAccessObjects;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;


namespace --correct namespace--
{

public class HomeController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult CreateAccount()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult AddGame(Game g, string Save)
    {
       
         --Code--
    }

    public ActionResult GameEdit(int id)
    {
        --Code--
    }
   
    public ActionResult DownloadGame(string path)
    {
        --Code--
    }

}
}
```

The code for the other controllers works perfectly.

Edit 2: web.config File

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, 
please visit
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
<add name="conString" connectionString="Data Source=localhost; 
database=DBName;Integrated Security=True;"/>
-->
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="conString" connectionString="server=BISIISDEV; 
        database=PolyGames;Integrated Security=True;"/>
    </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false"/>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2"/>
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" executionTimeout="3600" 
maxRequestLength="204857600" enable="true"/>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="204857600" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" 
publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" 
newVersion="3.5.0.2"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" 
publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" 
newVersion="12.0.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" 
publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" 
newVersion="1.1.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" 
publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" 
newVersion="1.6.5135.21930"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" 
publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" 
newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" 
publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" 
newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" 
publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.7.0" 
newVersion="5.2.7.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
<system.codedom>
<compilers>
</compilers>
</system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

Edit 3:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
<configSections>
<sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" 
type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, 
System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
   <section name="host" 
type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, 
 System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
  <section name="pages" 
type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, 
System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
 PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
</sectionGroup>
</configSections>

<system.web.webPages.razor>
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, 
System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace=project name />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>

<appSettings>
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
</appSettings>

<system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
  <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" 
 preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
 </handlers>
 </system.webServer>

 <system.web>
  <compilation>
    <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you show your whole home controller pls?

Comment: Thanks. And would be nice to  see how you config endpoints in your startup or web.config.

Comment: I can' t see any routing in web.config. you must be have something like route.config. Pls post it.